# Trying to use Tomcat Ant task in Gradle

Tags: tomcat, gradle, ant

I am in the process of migrating from from Ant to Gradle.  I can't seem to find a better way to managing my tomcat deployments in Grade so I am trying to use the Tomcat Ant tasks from within Gradle but I can't get it work.

Here is what I do in Ant which works

```
 <taskdef name="deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"/>

 <target name="deploy" description="Install web application"
      depends="dist">
    <deploy url="${url}" username="${username}" password="${password}"
        path="/${contextName}" war="${DIST}/${contextName}.war"/>
 </target>
```

So in Gradle and I am trying to use the Ant task like this

```
ant.taskdef(name:"deploy", classname:"org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask", 
    classpath: "PATH_TO_catalina-ant.jar")

ant.deploy(url="http://localhost:8080/manager/text" username="user" password="pass"
        path="/app" war="dist/app.war")
```

When I run the task with the `--debug` flag I can see that the task is getting loaded property from the JAR

```
 Class org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
```

But I get this error message

```
 Could not set unknown property 'war' for task ':deploy' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

WAR is definitely a property of this task but the fact that the error message is calling it `DefaultTask` makes me think the `taskdef` is not setup properly but I'm not sure.  In reality nothing is working because if I remove "war" then it just complains the same about the next property I defined.

I am using Gradle 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the task attributes with commas. You did this with the `taskdef` task, but they're missing in the `deploy` task.

```
ant.deploy(url="http://localhost:8080/manager/text", username:"user", password:"pass", path:"/app", war:"dist/app.war")
```

Comment: Thanks, I also had to replace the "=" with ":" just like I did with the `taskdef`